# Update Database Within mysqli_query

Tags: mysqli, sql-update, insert-update

Inside mysqli_query I have listed user details in a table and one of the column contains option to Activate or Deactivate the account. Clicking any of the option it should update Column Activate to Yes or No. I have included what I have right now

```
echo "<td>";
 if ($row['active'] == Yes) echo"<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-icon icon-left'><i class='entypo-cancel'></i>Deactivate</a>";                     
 else echo "<a href='#' class='btn btn-info btn-sm btn-icon icon-left'><i class='entypo-info'></i>Activate</a>";
echo "</td>";
```

I can I accomplish this?

I can included entire code at http://pastebin.com/hZ46M3JW

Comment: so what is the problem about updating db column?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($row['active'] == Yes)
```

Yes should be quoted; without quotes, the interpreter will try to find some variable/function/keyword called Yes (that likely doesn't exist).

```
if ($row['active'] == "Yes")
```